# Store XML HTML Word in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I want to store different contents into the Cassandra database. Example: I would consume a RSS feed and then store it in the Database. Similarly i would like to store HTML and Word documents in to the Cassandra database. I also searched and found how to store image content in to the Cassandra database. I'm using Java and Thrift.
Can anybody please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java, you should use the [Hector](https://github.com/rantav/hector) client rather than raw Thrift.  As far as storing the documents, you have numerous options.  The RSS feed and HTML docs can simply be stored as UTF8 text (as could the newer Word docx format), and older binary Word docs can be stored as bytes.